# Binomial distribution where probability of success is dependent on another binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, compound-distributions

How does one model the Binomial distribution where the probability of success is the result of another Binomial distribution.

For example, say I make 10 coin tosses many times and record the number of heads (*H*). Then for each set (*i*) of 10 coin tosses I put *Hi* black marbles, and 10-*Hi* white marbles in a jar and make 50 draws with replacement. How would I model the distribution of the black marble draws taking into account their dependence on the  previous Binomial distribution that generated their probability of success.

Answer (score 6):

This is known as a [compound distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution). Some compound distributions simplify, and can be recognized as another well-known distribution, but I don't think this binomial-binomial compound is one of those. (There is another type of binomial-binomial compound which does simplify to just a binomial, where you toss all coins, and then reflip the heads.)

I think the simplest way to handle the distribution is as a [mixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of $11$ different binomial distributions parametrized by the number of heads in the initial batch, from $0$ to $10$. There are other possibilities based on recognizing this as a compound of a multinomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks D. Zare for the response.  I'm the OP.  I spent a little more time looking into this and I believe another solution is to use a beta-binomial distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution).  The beta-binomial requires alpha and beta shape parameters like a beta distribution. In the context of the situation described above, alpha = beta = 5, which corresponds to the size of the first "coin toss" binomial. For small values of alpha and beta the beta-binomial distribution is more dispersed than a binomial.  As alpha and beta get larger the distribution converges on the binomial.